# How to assign value to an element of 2d array with dynamic size?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

I want to create an adjacency matrix for a graph without using any libraries. The problem is the size of the graph is not static and it increases over time. So I **can not** use a command like:

```
adj = [ [None for i in range(5)] for j in range(4) ]
```

and for example, assign 4 to element (1,1):

```
adj[1][1]=4
```

I have created an empty list called adj:

```
adj = []
```

now each time a node is added to the graph I add a list to adj:

```
adj.append([])
```

How can I assign a value to a specific element of the matrix, as I did with `q[1][1]=4` when the size was fixed?

Comment: This is pretty inefficient approach and it would be better for you to know it in advance or to preallocate big enough matrix. If such possibility does not exist, there is no other way than create new matrix on every new node. So every time a new node appears, you need to create a new row and column and the end of of your current matrix.

Comment: @SergeyIvanov What about **adjacency list**?  If I add elements in a list, how can I get or assign a specific element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with any default size and then use `extend` to add elements to a sublist, or add a new sublist.

```
adj = [ [0 for i in range(2)] for j in range(2) ]
print(adj)
#[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
adj[0].extend([1, 1])
#[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0]]
print(adj)
adj.extend([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
print(adj)
#[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Once you resize your list based on requirement, then you can assign your elements.

```
adj[0][0] = 2
adj[1][1] = 3
adj[2][2] = 4
print(adj)
#[[2, 0, 1, 1], [0, 3], [0, 0, 4, 0, 0]]
```